# Well-separated Points on Lateral Surface of a Cone

Tags: geometry

Is there a way to generate k points $x_1,\dots,x_k$ such that $\min_{ i \neq j } d(x_i,x_j) $ is as large as possible? The distance between any two points, $d(x_i,x_j)$, is defined as the minimum path from $x_i$ to $x_j$ via the cone's lateral surface.

Is there further a way to calculate the minimum distance based on the number of points and the cone dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cone is a developable surface. If you cut it open along a ray from the apex,
you get a flat sector. Place a pattern of points on this unfolding, being aware that
there are two images of the cut ray.
Something like this:

---

[image: ConePts]

---

You could use a hexagonal pattern instead of the rectangular grid I show above.
Then it is like packing pennies on the cone.

See also this question: [Packing disks on a cone](https://mathoverflow.net/q/191416/6094).